# fixed position nav makes elements below overlap

Tags: css, html

Im using a fixed nav bar that has a height of 100px, but the content below is overlapped by it. Currently I am giving the element directly below the nav a margin-top of 100px. Is this the correct way to do it or is there a style I can apply to the nav to fix this. The nav is permanent the elements below are constantly changing so I dont want to keep applying that margin-top to every new element.

Comment: Well if your nav has to be fixed position, then you need something to make up for its space. You can always wrap the nav in a container and give it the height of the nav itself so there is always that space. If you nav is always the first item on the page, you can always just pad the top of the body. Lot of ways to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like

```
<div id="nav">
     <!-- here u put your options -->
</div>

<script>
position : relative;
top : 0%;
height : 100px; 
</script>
```

after this part you can continue making your page with div with position: relative;. all those div will come beneath the nav without overlapping.